# Safari favicons mess

Tags: safari, bookmarks

I have been playing with Safari's favicon on my 2014 MacBook Pro (running Catalina) for a couple of days, replacing ugly or non existent icons of my bookmarks (mainly using [this](https://gist.github.com/dardo82/f7cc7c5c864fb5afa04bb12ecbcf3a9f)).

All of a sudden the database file and all the icons' images in `/Users/(me)/Library/Safari/Touch Icons Cache` got somehow locked.

The images in particular I cannot unlock or delete, even as root, even in recovery mode.

If I try to replace an icon, a new weird file show up in `.../Touch Icons Cache/Images` and I cannot erase it. The icon to be replaced has not changed or has become the new one only at the first launch of Safari.

I would like to continue to replace ugly icons of my bookmarks and I also would like to solve this locked folder mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by deleting the whole `Touch Icons Cache` folder.
I then replaced manually the icons.

If I try to use the [safari-favicons.sh code](https://gist.github.com/dardo82/f7cc7c5c864fb5afa04bb12ecbcf3a9f) the problem shows up again. I guess I'll adapt.